# MS Bot Framework: Begin Dialog When User Taps on Hero Card

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm having a Hero Card, which opens an URL when a users taps on it:

```
const message = new builder.Message(session);
    message.attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel);
    message.addAttachment(
        new builder.HeroCard(session)
            .title('Title')
            .tap(builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, 'https://www.google.com'))
            .images([builder.CardImage.create(session, url)]));
```

How can I change the `tap()` action so that instead of opening an URL a certain dialog is started? (Like I would do with `session.beginDialog('DialogID');`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `openUrl` to either `imBack` (if you want the user to see the message sent to the bot) or `postBack` (to hide the message sent to the bot).

So something like

```
.tap(builder.CardAction.imBack(session, 'I have been tapped'))
```